# Python: Doing calculations with elapsed time of an activity

Tags: python, dataframe, time, measurement

I have the following data of **elapsed time** of an activity:

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJgP5.png)

Is there any way to to add up the elapsed time for each acitvity, such that activity A has a total elapsed time of 08:15:00 and B 02:30:00? Thank you all so much for your help.

Note: I did not find any solution so far on stackoverflow. The format of the time measurement is provided by a third party and the original dataframe is large, which means that transformations of the time measurements e.g. by a for-loop take very long.

Comment: `df.groupby(['Activity'])['Time'].sum()`

Comment: Hy Epsi95, thank you for your comment. The problem is the "Time" measurement, which cannot be summed: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'

Comment: @LuckLukee check the answer

Comment: @LuckyLukee please display your sample data in a tabular format, as opposed to a link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pd.to_timedelta()` and `groupby`

```py
import pandas as pd

d = [['A', '08:00:00'],
    ['B', '02:00:00'],
    ['A', '00:15:00'],
    ['B', '00:30:00']]

df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['Activity', 'Time'])

df['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'])
df.groupby(['Activity']).sum()
```

```
Activity    Time
A          0 days 08:15:00
B          0 days 02:30:00
```

---

If you don't want days in the final then

```py
import re

df2 = df.groupby(['Activity']).sum()
df2['Time'] = df2['Time'].apply(lambda x: re.findall(r'days (.*)', str(x))[0])
df2
```

```
Activity    Time
A          08:15:00
B          02:30:00
```

Comment: Probably ought to include the import statement for pd in your answer code.

Comment: @Epsi95 that is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!